# running sessions in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

As everyone else, I have an optimizer and cost calculator as following:

```
with tf.name_scope("calc_cost"):
    cost_mini_batch = compute_cost(ZL, Y_mini_batch, parameters, lambd, 
                                   mb_size=tf.cast(X_mini_batch.shape[1], dtype=tf.float32))

with tf.name_scope("train"):
    optimizer =  tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(cost_mini_batch)
```

In my training execution, I run the following...

```
_ , minibatch_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost_mini_batch])
```

But I am a bit confused regarding how I should be reading this statement.
Since optimizer runs the cost_mini_batch anyway, I wonder if this statement can cause the problem that cost_mini_batch is run twice? The actual value I am interested in (for logging purposes) is the minibatch_cost. (I kind of would like to see that it is decreasing.) But I obviously at the same time want the training algorithm to run the optimizer.

I wonder if anyone having more experience than me can help me to read the sess.run(...) statement correctly i the formal way? I assume that the cost_mini_batch is not run twice here. For example, what would cause it to be run twice?

Answer (score 1):

**Tensorflow** work flow is:

```
1. build the Graph
2. run the graph in Session
```

as your code, you are defining `cost_mini_batch` and `optimizer` two elements in **Graph**,  after this, you invoke **Session** to run this **Graph**. so actually they will only run when you invoke `sess.run`.

Find more in [Graph and Sessions](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graphs#executing_a_graph_in_a_wzxhzdk130wzxhzdk131tfsessionwzxhzdk132wzxhzdk133)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
What confuses me is the way it is written.
IS there any difference between
sess.run([optimizer, cost_mini_batch])
and 
sess.run(optimizer)  ?

Comment: @edn read the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run): since running the optimizer requires evaluating the cost, both operations will be run for each call. The only difference is, if you omit `cost_mini_batch`, you will not be fetching its value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I unfortunately find official Tensorflow documentation quite useless. It feels like a spagetti, which doesnt take me anywhere, very few example code. It is mostly a time killer.